# Lazy Scroll loading in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have fetched users data from a wordpress site using ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://..../wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: {limit: 6, order: 'asc'}, 
  success : function(data){
    for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    $('div.about-us').append('<div class="col-md-4 single-grid '+data[i].id+'" onclick="myFunction(\'' + data[i] + '\')"><div class="col-md-11 text-center"><img src="'+data[i].profileImage+'"><h4>'+data[i].name+'</h4><strong>'+data[i].job_title+'</strong></div></div>');
    }

  }
```

I am appending each data dynamically. I have lot of data here "http://..../wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users". I want only 6 rows initially and if i scroll down it should load another 6 rows. I dont want to use jquery plugin. Overall what i want is lazy scroll loading without any plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
var scrollLimit = 500;  // Amount after which ajax() call initializes
var limit       = 3;    // item count
var offset      = 6;    // offset
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition >= scrollLimit)
    {   
        loadContent(limit, offset);  // loadContent method in which ajax() call is defined

        // Update values on each scroll
        scrollLimit = scrollLimit + 500;
        offset  = offset + 3;
    }
});
```

Comment: Even i specify limit to 6 it is giving me all the rows.

Comment: Then problem at your server side in query. @SwapnilPatil

Comment: You have to send `limit, offset` value on server side and use this in query with LIMIT and OFFSET

Answer (score 0):

Instead limit: 6 tried like this:

```
data : {per_page:6, page:page_no}
```

Solved my problem. Thanks